# Como ordenar uma coluna de um arquivo sem ordenar as linhas?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Eu tenho um arquivo que possui três colunas, e várias linhas.
A segunda coluna é composta por valores numéricos, e eu quero reorganiza-la, em ordem crescente, mas sem que afete a coluna anterior e a posterior à essa.

```
exemplo do arquivo:

7.31937  736    /tmp/ref13
7.3223   5373   /tmp/ref13
7.32816  768    /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5370   /tmp/ref10

o que eu quero:


7.31937  736    /tmp/ref13
7.3223   768    /tmp/ref13
7.32816  5370   /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5373   /tmp/ref10
```

eu tentei `sort -k2 -n`, mas este comando está movimentando as outras colunas =(

Alguém me ajuda?
Valeu!

Edit:

```
[Resolvido]Comando utilizado:

`paste -d' '  <(awk '{print $1}' nome_arquivo) <(awk '{print $2}' nome_arquivo | sort -n) <(awk '{print $3}' nome_arquivo)`
```

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Depois, edite sua pergunta e insira o código do que você já tentou...

Comment: Sim, ficou boa a pergunta agora.. Está mais clara e mais fácil para entender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2

awk '{ print $1 }' $INPUT           > $$.1
awk '{ print $2 }' $INPUT | sort -n > $$.2
awk '{ print $2 }' $INPUT           > $$.3

paste $$.1 $$.2 $$.3 > $OUTPUT
rm $$1 $$.2 $$.3
```